# Is there an app that helps you move files without drag-and-drop?

Tags: finder

I know that I can move files at the command line, but I'm looking for an elegant desktop solution besides the traditional drag-and-drop of the Finder.

Basically, I want to right-click on a file and have a menu option that says "Move..." with a bunch of recently moved locations, or with a dialog box letting me choose the location.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am aware that I can move files in Lion using a copy&move workflow, drag&drop workflow, or command line. To me, working with nested folders in the Finder is very slow and cumbersome. I'm looking for a faster and more elegant solution. I will try some of the suggestions below. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

One option is to use the built-in "Copy" and "Move Item Here" options:

1. Right-click on the source:

   [image]
2. Hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> while right-clicking at the destination:

   [image]

(Of course, these can also be done using keyboard shortcuts!)

Comment: From what I can gather, this still necessitates that I navigate to the folder in the Finder, which is precisely the thing I'd like to avoid. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Yes it does, so if that's what you're trying to avoid then this may not be your answer. Of course, if you're just trying to navigate quickly you can use ⌘N and ⇧⌘G and type in a path.

Answer (score 3):

OS X Lion has [build-in copy & move item function](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/29/cut-and-paste-mac-os-x-lion/). If you're using (Snow) Leopard, my favorite software is [Total Finder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [alfred](http://support.alfredapp.com/tutorials%3awork-with-files).

1. Launch Alfred
2. Key in the name of the file that you want to move
3. Press Ctrl
4. Select *Move to...*
5. Type name of destination folder

Don't even need to use the mouse. And it's a lot more easier than it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

My app of choice for this is [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Xtrafinder gives you what you are looking for.

I came across this post looking for the same thing, a way to "right-click on a file and have a menu option that says "Move..." with a bunch of recently moved locations, or with a dialog box letting me choose the location." but I didn't find it here.

So I kept looking.

And found it here: http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/

Super simple.

You can set up a "Copy to..." menu item, and a "Move to..." keyboard shortcut (no menu item for "Move to..." for some reason, but I just set it to CMND + -> (right arrow) and its smooth as can be.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [FileCutter](http://www.splook.com/Software/FileCutter.html) (on 10.5.8), which does exactly what you're asking about. According to its webpage though there's no support for contextual menu plugins in 10.6+ so I'm not sure if you find it very useful (but see [this link](http://www.abracode.com/free/cmworkshop/shortcuts.html)).

Answer (score 0):

My app of choice for this is [moveAddict](http://kapeli.com/) although it doesn't have the 'recent places' feature that you asked for.

(I'm not aware of any app which does.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try QuollEyeTree, a Mac OS X file manager inspired by [XTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTree).

It features a full basic set of file operations, copy, move, rename, delete for files, directories and tagged files file filtering and tagging.

Most operations can be done with the keyboard, mouse or menu, so it should satisfy most - although there is no drag and drop.

It can be downloaded from http://binnie.id.au/Ian/TreeApp.html, which also shows a screenshot.